# Adding custom view in a loop cause out of memory error

Tags: android, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I am trying to add a custom view multiple times from xml to another view in an android activity. But it causes out of memory error after opening and closing that activity few times. Here is the code:

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(currentActivity.getApplicationContext());
FlowLayout postsLayout = (FlowLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_posts);
postsLayout.removeAllViews();

for (final Post post : postsData) {



                RelativeLayout profilePostItem = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.drawer_item, null);
                ImageView postPic = (ImageView) profilePostItem.findViewById(R.id.post_pic);

                String picUrl = post.getSingleImageURL();

                if(picUrl != null && !picUrl.equals("null"))
                {
                    postPic.setTag(picUrl);
                    imageLoader.DisplayImage(picUrl, currentActivity, postPic, R.drawable.default_item);

                }



                profilePostItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity, PostDetailsActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("postID", Integer.toString(post.getPostId()));
                        currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                postsLayout.addView(profilePostItem);

            }
```

and here is the drawer_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"              
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                >


<ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/post_pic"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"       
        android:background="#FFFFFF" 
        android:src="@drawable/default_user_pic"
    />   


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the LogCat output:

```
    09-06 22:32:45.566: D/dalvikvm(11857): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed <1K, 6% free 46549K/49095K, paused 67ms, total 67ms
09-06 22:32:45.566: E/dalvikvm-heap(11857): Out of memory on a 67816-byte allocation.
09-06 22:32:45.566: I/dalvikvm(11857): "Thread-15875" prio=4 tid=53 RUNNABLE
09-06 22:32:45.566: I/dalvikvm(11857):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4325e6d8 self=0x53269790
09-06 22:32:45.566: I/dalvikvm(11857):   | sysTid=12239 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1395039200
09-06 22:32:45.566: I/dalvikvm(11857):   | schedstat=( 124808833 28013003 46 ) utm=10 stm=1 core=1
09-06 22:32:45.566: I/dalvikvm(11857):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
09-06 22:32:45.566: I/dalvikvm(11857):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:652)
09-06 22:32:45.566: I/dalvikvm(11857):   at com.company.testapp.utils.ImageLoader.decodeFile(ImageLoader.java:139)
09-06 22:32:45.566: I/dalvikvm(11857):   at com.company.testapp.utils.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:81)
09-06 22:32:45.566: I/dalvikvm(11857):   at com.company.testapp.utils.ImageLoader.access$0(ImageLoader.java:73)
09-06 22:32:45.566: I/dalvikvm(11857):   at com.company.testapp.utils.ImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(ImageLoader.java:196)
09-06 22:32:45.566: D/skia(11857): --- decoder->decode returned false
09-06 22:32:45.566: W/dalvikvm(11857): threadid=53: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41aee2a0)
09-06 22:32:45.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11857): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-15875
09-06 22:32:45.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11857): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
09-06 22:32:45.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11857):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
09-06 22:32:45.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11857):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:652)
09-06 22:32:45.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11857):    at com.company.testapp.utils.ImageLoader.decodeFile(ImageLoader.java:139)
09-06 22:32:45.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11857):    at com.company.testapp.utils.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:81)
09-06 22:32:45.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11857):    at com.company.testapp.utils.ImageLoader.access$0(ImageLoader.java:73)
09-06 22:32:45.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11857):    at com.company.testapp.utils.ImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(ImageLoader.java:196)
09-06 22:32:45.651: I/dalvikvm-heap(11857): Clamp target GC heap from 48.757MB to 48.000MB
09-06 22:32:45.651: D/dalvikvm(11857): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 180K, 6% free 46583K/49159K, paused 68ms, total 68ms
09-06 22:32:45.651: I/dalvikvm-heap(11857): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 63616-byte allocation
09-06 22:32:45.736: I/dalvikvm-heap(11857): Clamp target GC heap from 48.757MB to 48.000MB
09-06 22:32:45.736: D/dalvikvm(11857): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 0K, 6% free 46583K/49159K, paused 82ms, total 82ms
09-06 22:32:45.736: E/dalvikvm-heap(11857): Out of memory on a 63616-byte allocation.
09-06 22:32:45.736: I/dalvikvm(11857): "Thread-15874" prio=4 tid=49 RUNNABLE
```

Can anyone tell why it is leaking memory?

Comment: not clear to me anyway - I'd say (as I often do) add some Log.d's - suspect areas *might* be removeAllViews(), imageLoader().

Comment: added logcat output to question.

Comment: yup - looks like it's the imageLoader... how big are the images?  I'd put a try-catch around that code too (but you will get the same error msg obviously as log cat, yet that can help pin it down.)  Have you tried compressing the bitmaps or using a bitmap cache ? (I had a similar headache very recently :)

Comment: I don't think it's size of the image causing the problem. Something else is wrong here. Because, I tried to analyze this in ddms and MAT and noticed that when first time activity opens it occupies 10mb, on next open it becomes 15mb, and then on next open 20mb and when it reaches 40mb, it crashes with OOM error. Shouldn't GC clear memory whenever I close activity?

Comment: GC has a mind of its own ... note tho the heap clamping and soft references. The leak is from something very large - that could only be the app & its res, the images, or both. (Or an os bug/oversight that you accidentally stepped on - not as likely.)  Have you tried commenting out sections of code piece by piece until crash goes away ?

Comment: oh - and you could force the GC with a call to see if that improves. I'd not do that in production code, however :))

Comment: If I comment imageLoader.display() line, crash goes away and GC revokes the memory on activity close. But this is not the solution :)

Comment: FYI average image size is 8kb, and there are 40 images in total, but only 4 visible at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by replacing my ImageLoader with [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

Answer (score 2):

Its a [**known bug**](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8488), its not because of large files. Since Android Caches the Drawables, its going out of memory after using few images. But i found alternate way for it, by skipping the android default cache system.

**Soultion**:
Create a drawable folder in Assets and move the images to "drawable" folder in assets and use the following function to get BitmapDrawable

```
public static Drawable getAssetImage(Context context, String filename) throws IOException {
    AssetManager assets = context.getResources().getAssets();
    InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream((assets.open("drawable/" + filename + ".png")));
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffer);
    return new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
}
```

Refrence : https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6116316/revisions

Comment: well, there you go - bug in os afterall ! +1